# How can I connect to a cisco switch via serial console cable from powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cisco, remote-access, serial

I don't actually need to perform any operations on the switch. I just need to verify it's there.

I have some remote servers that I need to verify have the blue serial console cable hooked up correctly. Rather than RDC into each of them and copy/configure putty just to hit enter a couple times, I'd like to use "enter-pssession" to remotely connect to PowerShell and access COM1 that way.

I've tried using this, but get no feedback on the console.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/08/31/writing-and-reading-info-from-serial-ports/

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Slap `enter-pssession -computername XXXXXXX` in front of this to remotely connect to a system to check.

```
$com = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(“COM1”)
$com.open()
$com.write([char]13)
$com.ReadExisting()
```

Comment: This is neat. I almost wanted to tell you (tongue in cheek) to open up Powershell, and type "putty.exe" ;)

Comment: Hey, if putty would make a connection to a remote system first and then connect to the serial port, I would have marked your comment as the answer :-)

Comment: Don't forget to mark it answered...